# c# - Button displaying/hiding password from text box

Tags: c#

I am currently making a c# application, in which I am using a text box with property `PasswordChar` - •. However, this text box has a button like the one below:

[image]

However, as a student and amateur, I am unable to make an `if` code for the button, which when pressed, shows or hides the real numbers of the password.
I think it should be something like this:

```
private void metroTextBox1_ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (metroTextBox1.PasswordChar='\•') metroTextBox1.PasswordChar = '\0';
        else metroTextBox1.PasswordChar = '\•';
    }
```

but I think I have at least 1 mistake here.

Please, help!

Comment: Note that `UseSystemPasswordChar` always overrides `PasswordChar` if set to `true`. And that is probably what you want. So my recommendation would be always keep `PasswordChar` set to 0, and just toggle `UseSystemPasswordChar` on/off (true/false).

Comment: use `==` for comparison, `=` for assignment. And you don't need to use the escape character (`\`) for the character `•`

Comment: Thank you for your reply.Will definetly experiment with this method. :-)

Comment: @RufusL Thank you. The answer below also stated this mistake in the code. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistakes are in this :

```
textBox1.PasswordChar = '\•'
```

You must use `==` instead of `=` and '•' instead of '\•'

```
textBox1.PasswordChar == '•'
```

It worth be added as  @Cody Gray has already noted  that it is better to use `UseSystemPasswordChar`

Comment: Just to use this thread, instead of creating a new one, just for a simple question - I have set the image of the text box button. However, I want when clicked, the image to change to another one. However, VS does not recognise the button, therefore, I cannot change the image! I will be happy if you help me, of course if you are familiar with the metro ui nudget in VS 2013. EDIT: I have found it out!

Comment: @DanielHalachev How can VS not recognise the button when you have already handling that button click event? :)